# .net MVC Windows authentication sign in as another user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, windows-authentication

I am building an application using .net MVC and I get stuck in one of the requirement.

The application is an intranet website (WEB_A) and the authentication mode is windows authentication. However there are two ways the user can go into the website, one of them is from another internal website.(WEB_B) and the other is direct.

There is one special scenario

1. user_A logon to the computer,
2. user logon to web_B with user_B password (they don't use windows authentication, but the username are within the same database)
3. user_B click on the link from web_B and jump to web_A( what happen after user_B click on the link will be Web_B will open a window and then post those credential information to Web_A. Web_A will capture that and do whatever it needs to do)

I want web_A to somehow treat user_B is the login user instead of user_A (the user logon to the computer)

If a user go to the website (WEB_A) directly, we will just use the current logon user as the result.

Comment: Are you using a web-service to login to Web_B? If so you can use the same web-service to check if user credentials are correct and set them as logged in.

Comment: Web_B will open a window and then post those credential information to Web_A. Web_A will capture that and do whatever it needs to do